# How to initialize child object in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Hibernate.initialize(fooA);
Hibernate.initialize(fooA.getfooB()); <--- org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Here is more info about my POJOs

```
public class Foo{
  private String name;
  private FooA fooA;
}

public class FooA{
  private String name;
  private FooB fooB;
}

public class FooB{
  private String name;
}
```

Does Hibernate.initialize(object) close the current session?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate.initialize( ... ) won't close the current session.  In the code snippet above you are creating a session and then calling initialize on an object (fooA) which is not associated with that Session.

You can reattach fooA to the session with a `session.refresh( fooA );` call.  After reattaching your object the second call to `intialise` should behave as expected.

If you find yourself needing to initialize proxies like this frequently it might be an indicator that Lazy Initialization is not preferrable due to the (n-1) select problem.  Food for thought!